# Connecting points - plugin problem QGIS

Tags: qgis, road

I have a question related to connecting points in QGIS. I am doing a project relating to transport. I have a layer of points (bus stops) and I have to connect them according to a timetable (as runs a bus line). Lines must proceed on the road (I have layer of roads combined with OpenStreetMap). I found the plugin Online Routing Mapper, but in this plugin are only two points (start and stop) and making line where each has 15 or more points is time-consuming. Can someone please me to prompt another method of how to do it? The plugin of which I mentioned would meet my needs if I could add more points.

Answer (score 2):

There is an experimental QGIS plugin (you need to mark "Show also experimental plugins" in Plugins|Settings) named **PointsToPaths** that converts points to lines with verticies grouped by a text or integer field and ordered by an integer or date string field. You can try out it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try Points2One plugin. It converts points to lines.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your advice. However, the lines must run along existing roads (marking the buses lines) and this is my main problem. Using these plug-ins I combine points with stright lines.